# Identifying a trend in binomial experiments

Tags: statistical-significance, binomial-distribution, survey, trend

I have a survey running each month that's answered each time by a random set of people. I want to investigate the trend in a particular set of questions to see whether opinions are changing over time.

This is a fairly standard survey research question but as far as I know, the usual approach is just to sig test each successive pair of results.  But that doesn't incorporate the long term movement.

Is there a better way of treating the data, other than multiple binomial Sig tests, to identify change over time.

Comment: Do you think (conditional on the trend) the outcomes would be independent, or could there be time-dependence as well?

Comment: Other than the trend measuring a shift in attitude, it shouldn't be time-dependent I don't think.

Comment: Then perhaps a logistic regression with time as a predictor?

Comment: I see where you're going but could you perhaps elaborate a little? How might this be used to identify a trend?

Comment: It would model an increasing or decreasing proportions of 1's against time. More specifically, it fits a model with linearly changing log-odds. So you could fit a model of the form $P(Y=1) = p = f(t)$, where $f(t) = 1/[1+\exp(-\alpha-\beta t)]$, or $\text{logit}(p) = \alpha+\beta t$. This way other predictors, including ones unrelated to time, may be included if needed. For more general forms of trend, there are a number of choices, but I'd probably lean toward generalized additive models. (You might still want to assess whether there's indication of time-dependence in model assessment.)